# Suitescript - nlapiSendEmail() - Can I delay an email through script to send on certain date?

Tags: email, send, netsuite, suitescript

I currently have a script that triggers on save that sends out an email. However, under certain criteria, I would like to still trigger the script on save but delay the email until a certain date. Is this possible? How would that be written?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way you could 'schedule' the email using the existing APIs.  

What I'd do is create a custom field on the record in question to 'flag' it for said email delivery and set it 'on save' when necessary.  Then, a scheduled script could search for records with said flag, evaluate whatever date criteria you needed to apply, and send the emails at the appropriate times and reset the flag.

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to you NetSuite Workflow.  You can put the record in a workflow state based on you condition.  On that workflow state have a delay transition to another state after x days which will send the email.

Look at the SuiteAnswer for drop marketing for sample workflows.

Answer (score 1):

@scheppsr77's answer is a good idea.

Another way to do it would be to create a new custom record type that holds the email information and the date you want to send it on.  Then have a script that runs periodically checking for any emails to send.  Basically it could run like a cron job.  I've done that before, for certain items that needed to be re-run or needed to delay.